# MYSQL/PHP : 'AS' xnumber as always positive number

Tags: php, mysql

I hit a wall in my code where I need the totalnumber to always be positive.

So there is a multiplier that is randomly generated. It can be -1 or 1.

```
$query = "SELECT *, A * $MULTIPLIER1 + B * $MULTIPLIER2 + C * $MULTIPLIER3 AS totalnumber FROM data_table
ORDER BY totalscore DESC
LIMIT 2"
```

This code itself works. However, if there are TOO many negative multiplier the "totalnumber" becomes a negative number thus ruining the ORDER BY.

I need the "totalnumber" to always be a POSITIVE number WITHOUT tampering the A, B, C multipliers, meaning A*multi , B*multi , C*multi can be negative thus changing the totalnumber. I hope that makes sense... How do I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php

**abs** - Returns the absolute value of number.

```
echo abs(-15);
15
```

You can also do this in MySQL

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html

```
SELECT ABS(-15);
15
```

Comment: So can I do... SELECT ABS(totalnumber); ??

Comment: SELECT ABS(A * $MULTIPLIER1 + B * $MULTIPLIER2 + C * $MULTIPLIER3) as totalnumber

Comment: So according to my math and how my stupid system is set it gets different results that looks incorrect. Is there a possibility to reverse the order of DESC if the # is negative?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `abs()` to convert negatives to positives.  However, I suspect that you want `greatest()`:

```
GREATEST(A * $MULTIPLIER1 + B * $MULTIPLIER2 + C * $MULTIPLIER3, 0) AS totalnumber
```

This will convert any negative value to 0.

Comment: I need negative numbers to affect the totalnumber. However, I just need the totalnumber to be positive. As in, if the multipliers made the totalnumber -10, then it just needs to be +10.

Comment: @user2515606 . . . Under many circumstances, it would make sense to give the negative numbers a value of 0 (or perhaps 1).

Answer (score 0):

You could square the final result then take the square root, or better use the `ABS` operator [- link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx).